How to Balance Two Majors and a Minor with Course Overlap and Accreditation Concerns
I'm in a bit of a pickle and could use some advice. I'm currently juggling two majors and a minor, and it's starting to get overwhelming. Here’s the rundown:
Majors: Philosophy at Kharazmi University and Computer Science at Mehralborz University (which is online and not fully accredited)
Minor: Mathematics at Kharazmi University
One of my main issues is that I have to take the same math courses for both my math minor and my Computer Science degree at Mehralborz University. This makes things even more complicated because:

Managing my time has become a real challenge.
I'm worried about the lack of accreditation at Mehralborz University and what that means for my career.
The overlap in math courses makes it harder to keep things straight.

Additionally, I'm an Iranian student who wants to study abroad for my postgraduate studies. This adds another layer of concern about how my current choices might impact my future applications.
I’d love some advice on how to manage my time better, whether I should consider resigning from either my math minor or my Computer Science major, and how all of this might affect my postgraduate applications.
Any insights or experiences would be really helpful!

I assume it is not possible to simply take all three programs at the accredited university? Which subject is it that you want to study at the postgraduate level?

What do you mean by "the overlap...is making it harder to keep things straight"? I would have thought the overlap would make things easier, since you have less to learn.

Hey @cag51 . Although my academic interests are really diverse, but I want to pursue Logic (mathematical, philosophical and computational) for my postgraduate studies.
And by that phrase, I mean that it is becoming very frustrating and time-wasting to take the same courses in both degrees.

Perhaps you should ask yourself whether you would have a better record if you stick to one university and fewer fields. Spreading yourself this thin feels suboptimal.

And thinking a bit more, I wonder whether it isn't math you should emphasize, given your comment about grad study. Math major with a philosophy minor would seem to cover that better than with a math minor. Take mathematical logic (formal logic) and discrete math. A CS degree isn't essential for what you intend, though programming is.

What sort of advice have your advisors given you?


I want to pursue Logic (mathematical, philosophical and computational) for my postgraduate studies

Is this why you think you need to have some sort of (major or minor) degree in each?
Although these are not really my area of expertise, I suspect that this is not really how things work at the postgraduate level in academia: you'll have to find some way of specializing, and even if you work at the boundaries of fields it's more likely you'll get there naturally from what is covered in one major, rather than needing bits of each. The undergraduate education in any of them is likely to be quite superficial.
If you had all these things on your CV, I would probably infer that you have trouble with focus, or perhaps that you decided to pick up the CS degree as a hedge against problems with a career in philosophy. I might separately infer that if you chose a minor rather than a major in math because you felt insecure about your math abilities - I'm not sure if that accurately describes the rigor of the philosophy versus math programs at your institution, though, of course.
I'm certainly biased with a US perspective, but my impression also is that a minor does not have much value besides encouraging you to focus on a few more courses in a given area. If you intend to do more academic work in Math, you probably want to take the courses that someone with a math major would take, with only a minor you're going to come up short.
The online CS degree seems to me like a distraction. I would think far less about what various titles you are earning and think much more about what you are actually learning.
